# Different versions of DIGIC processors, is there any difference in image quality?

Tags: canon, image-quality

While comparing the features of Canon 400D and 1000D, I've noticed that Canon 1000D has an improved DIGIC III processor, over the DIGIC II for Canon 400D.

From Wikipedia:

> The DIGIC III Image Processor was
>   advertised to deliver superior image
>   quality, faster operation and extended
>   battery life compared to its
>   predecessor.

Will a newer version of the DIGIC processor provide visible improvements of image quality? What about when shooting in RAW?

I understand that newer versions may perform faster (when focusing, or a higher frame rate) and have features such as face detection and live view, but that is of no importance to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is Yes and No.  It will indeed provide improvements in image quality when shooting **jpeg**, but the raw image is unaffected by DIGIC processing, it being the raw unprocessed data.  Here is an article produced by Canon about Digic processing A/D conversion and RAW files:

http://www.usa.canon.com/dlc/controller?act=GetArticleAct&articleID=2748

Most importantly, the increase in Bit Depth of the DIGIC IV processor:

> Equally important are the image quality benefits provided by the DIGIC 4’s integrated 14-bit Analog-to-Digital (A/D) converter...

Unfortunately for your specific DIGIC III question its mostly about the advantages of DIGIC IV :p

Comment: It is difficult to find exactly what the DIGIC processor does, but it clearly does much more than JPEG conversion and is involved in fundamental parts of the raw image creation pipeline, including autofocusing and noise reduction.  See http://www.dpreview.com/news/0209/02091601canontech.asp or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeNRKvX1kLo .  Therefore we should conclude that raw image quality *will* be affected by improvements in this processor.

Comment: Unless you turn off all the image processing, which is probably a good idea anyways (e.g. no noise reduction, etc...).

Comment: @Fake The quotation specifically mentions the DIGIC 4 includes the ADC.  Without that, there would be no raw image, period.  This causes me to suspect that some of the advertised "noise reduction" occurs within the digitization of the analog signal itself and therefore cannot be turned off.

Comment: @whuber - Aside from correlated-double-sampling (which is used in *Every* digital camera out there, and really doesn't count as "noise reduction"), everything else is done in post-processing. I know my 5D has the option to turn off noise reduction.

Comment: I should probably point out that I have done some design work on the analog front-end for CCD cameras for astronomical work.

Comment: @Fake I respect that: it's difficult, without being in the business, to penetrate the marketing gloss.  But are you saying the DIGIC processor does *not* include the ADC?  Or are you just implying that all ADCs are essentially the same so that any improvements in DIGIC IV or DIGIC III must entirely be in post-processing?

Comment: The latter. An ADC has basically one main characteristic - It's noise (there are others, linearity, sample-rate,  etc... but they effect picture quality much less), but there is really no noise-processing done in the ADC.  There are other techniques, like double-correlated sampling, but those are done in processing *after* the ADC..

Comment: At this point, you can buy a competitive 14 or 16 bit ADC from many companies - National Semiconductor, Analog Devices, TI, Linear Technologies, etc... They're all good enough they they're pretty much genericised. (There are many implementation details, sample rate, etc... but within a specification range, they're pretty similar)

Comment: Basically, an ADC does one thing. It converts an analog voltage into a digital number. There are many ways to do this, but there really no noise reduction in the actual process. You may work to reduce the noise on the analog voltage, using analog filters, or post-process the digital output, but the actual conversion is pretty much a single-step operation

Comment: Besides, the other noise sources in a camera system pretty much dominate the ADC noise.